# Библиотека BeautifulSoup, парсинг html страницы. Необходимо выбрать n-ый подходящий элемент

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')    
soup.find_all('tr')[0].td.next_sibling.next_sibling.get_text()
```

Мне нужно из первого элемента массива достать третий тег td. Для этого я два раза делаю .next_sibling. Как можно укоротить эту строчку? Если понадобиться 200-ый тег, я же не буду 199 раз писать .next_sibling. В документации найти не смог.

Comment: в таких вопросах принято приводить примеры данных... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')    
soup.find_all('tr')[0].td[3]
```

не пойдет?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: какой вопрос такой и ответ)